# I am getting undefined variable on second page of user search function please solve this issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

On first page showing data but when i click on next page then i am
getting
" Undefined variable: users (View: C:\wamps\www\service-
portal\resources\views\users\index.blade.php)"

```
public function usersearch(Request $request)
{
    $first_name=$request->first_name;
    $email=$request->email;
    $status=$request->status;
    $mobile_number=$request->mobile_number;
    if($request->has('first_name') && $request->has('email')  && $request- 
       >has('mobile_number')  && $request->has('status') )
    {
        
        $users=User::where([
            ['first_name', 'like', '%'.$first_name.'%'],
            ['email', 'like', '%'.$email.'%'],
            ['mobile_number', 'like', '%'.$mobile_number.'%'],
            ['status', 'like', '%'.$status.'%'],
        ])->paginate(5);
        return view('users.index',compact('users'));
               
    }
 Web.php
 Route::Resource('user','UsersController');
 Route::get('/usersearch', 'UsersController@usersearch');
```

Comment: Share full code sample.

Comment: Post your controller and route

Comment: when click on search box it shows me data of first page but when i click on second page it giving me undefined variable users but when i am not seraching then pagination works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view you need to pass your variable on every pages :

```
public function usersearch(Request $request)
{
    $first_name = $request->first_name;
    $email = $request->email;
    $status = $request->status;
    $mobile_number = $request->mobile_number;
    if($request->has('first_name') && $request->has('email')  && $request- 
       >has('mobile_number')  && $request->has('status') )
    {
        
        $users=User::where([
            ['first_name', 'like', '%'.$first_name.'%'],
            ['email', 'like', '%'.$email.'%'],
            ['mobile_number', 'like', '%'.$mobile_number.'%'],
            ['status', 'like', '%'.$status.'%'],
        ])->paginate(5);
        return view('users.index',compact('users','first_name', 'email', 'status', 'mobile_number'));
               
}
```

In your blade call your pagination like this :

```
{{ $users->appends(['first_name' => $first_name, 'email' => $email, 'status' => $status, 'mobile_number' => $mobile_number])->links() }}
```

Comment: thanks working code , change 'email'=>$email  in call of pagination in blade

Comment: @Bhagyashree Kumari, opps , its a typo, forget to give `$`. thanks.